# Show that a cycle of length $p$ and a cycle of length $q$ in $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if $p = q$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Show that a cycle of length $p$ and a cycle of length $q$ in $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if $p=q$.

First of all, I'm a bit confused about the meaning of '... are conjugate'. Does this mean that $S_n$ acts by conjugation on both of them?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$. $\sigma,\tau$ conjugate means that there is a $\rho\in S_n$ such that $\tau=\rho\sigma\rho^{-1}$.